# manual Instance Show definition causes Stack Space Overflow

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, stack, overflow

When I write manually a simple show instance for the PhisicalCell datatype, the program consumes all the space. When deriving his own version of Show, this doesn't happen. Why?

here is a stripped-down version of the code I'm writing:

```
import Data.Array

type Dimensions = (Int, Int)
type Position = (Int, Int)
data PipeType = Vertical | Horizontal | UpLeft | UpRight | DownLeft | DownRight deriving (Show)

data PhisicalCell = AirCell
                  | PipeCell PipeType
                  | DeathCell
                  | RecipientCell Object
                  -- deriving (Show) SEE THE PROBLEM BELOW  

data Object = Pipe { pipeType :: PipeType  -- tipo di tubo
                   , position :: Position  -- posizione del tubo
                   , movable  :: Bool      -- se posso muoverlo
                   }
            | Bowl { position   :: Position                 -- posizione dell'angolo in alto a sinistra
                   , dimensions :: Dimensions               -- dimensioni (orizzontale, verticale)
                   , waterMax   :: Int                      -- quanta acqua puo' contenere al massimo
                   , waterStart :: Int                      -- con quanta acqua parte 
                   , hatch      :: Maybe Position           -- un eventuale casella di sbocco
                   , sourceIn   :: [Position]               -- posti da cui l'acqua entra
                   , movable    :: Bool                     -- se posso muoverlo
                   }
            | Death
            deriving (Show)

data Level = Level Dimensions [Object]
type LevelTable = Array Dimensions PhisicalCell

-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM -- 
instance Show PhisicalCell where
show AirCell = " "
show (PipeCell _) = "P"
show DeathCell = "X"
show (RecipientCell _) = "U"

both :: (a -> b) -> (a,a) -> (b,b)
both f (a,b) = (f a, f b)

levelTable :: Level -> LevelTable
levelTable (Level dim _) = initial
  where initial = array ((0,0), both (+1) dim) $
                    [((x,y), AirCell) | x <- [1..fst dim], y <- [1..snd dim] ]
                    ++ [((x,y), DeathCell) | x <- [0..fst dim + 1], y <- [0, snd dim + 1]]
                    ++ [((x,y), DeathCell) | x <- [0, fst dim + 1], y <- [0..snd dim + 1]]

main = print $ levelTable (Level (8,12) [])
```

Comment: is it spaced like this? You need extra space on the left of `show AirCell = ...` etc, for them to appear as part of `instance Show PhisicalCell`. Stack Overflow goes away for me, when I do that spacing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just realized that. But anyway, why is giving me this stack overflow error?

Comment: You get a stack overflow because you declared PhisicalCell to be a instance of show, but left the function undefined - looking at the dump, the default placed there is a recursive call to itself: `show = show`

Answer (score 7):

[The `Show` type class has mutually referencing default implementations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Show.html#Show):

```
class  Show a  where
    -- | Convert a value to a readable 'String'.
    --
    -- 'showsPrec' should satisfy the law
    -- ...
    ...
    showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
    show x          = shows x ""
    showList ls   s = showList__ shows ls s

...

shows           :: (Show a) => a -> ShowS
shows           =  showsPrec 0
```

So if you declare a `Show` instance without defining any of the methods

```
instance Show where

nextNewFunction :: Bla
...
```

GHC will happily compile all the default ones, so there won't be any errors. However, as soon as you try to *use* any of them, your trapped in a loop as deadly as your `Objects`... and the mutual recursion will eventually blow the stack.

Now, your code doesn't quite look as if you have such an empty `instance Show` declarion, but in fact you do: because of the wrong indentation, the `show` you define there is recognised as a new free top-level function that merely happens to have the same name as `GHC.Show.show`. You could add

```
show :: PhisicalCell -> String
```

to your file and get the same result as now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem does actually lie in the spacing that Sassa NF points out.  When I indent the show, it works (and when I don't, I get the stack overflow).  Without the indent, you're defining a top-level `show` function that is never used, and the `show` function for the `Show` instance of `PhisicalCell` has an undefined `show` function, which causes the problem.